# Finding symbolic solutions to nonlinear system of algebraic equations using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, numerical-methods, nonlinear-equation

Here are a system of two nonlinear equations :

[image]

In an answer to a previous question it has been shown that this system of equations doesn't possess explicit solutions([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77029161/sympys-solve-function-doesnt-yield-all-the-solutions)). But it is also noted that this system of equations is *already an implicit representation of solutions to the system*.

My questions are:

Can anyone explain what does *implicit representation of the solutions to the system* mean ?

Can I exploit this feature to obtain analytical expressions for x and y using sympy ?

Comment: The system encodes its solutions, you can not read off the solutions directly, so it is an implicit representation. Solving the system means to simplify these implicit representations until some part or all of them can be made explicit.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: The question is ill-posed because you ask for "analytical expressions" which means that you are already asking for an *explicit* representation of the solutions and as explained no such representation exists. The question is: if someone could give you an explicit representation of the solutions then what would you use it for? Then the question you should be asking here is: how can I achieve my actual goal *without* having an explicit representation of the solutions? No one can answer that question if all you ask for is explicit solutions.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin okay ...now i understand your point.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Can you give an example where this approach has been used ?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate to an approximation of the solution if you have values for the constants `a,b,c,d,g,h`. Numerical solvers do not need an explicit representation for `x` and `y`, they just need two expressions that define the desired relationships. That's what you have. They implicitly define what `x` and `y` must be in terms of those relationships.

By graphing or guessing or some other means you get an initial guess for the solution and then let the numerical solver take that guess and refine it to a desired precision. This is done whenever someone wants a solution to one or more equations that cannot be solved explicitly.

In your case it might look like this:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> a = 0.12
>>> b = -2.031529100521498e-30
>>> c = b
>>> d = 1
>>> g = 11
>>> h = 0
>>> def eqs():
...   F = (y + a/2)*x*(2*x**2 - 2*y*a + 2*d**2 + b + c) - (x*y*g**2)
...   G = (x**2 - y*a + b + d**2)*(x**2 - y*a + c+d**2) - 4*((y+a/2)**2)*x**2 - (h**2 + (x**2)*(g**2))
...   return F, G
>>> nsolve(eqs(),(x,y),(1,1))
Matrix([
[  0.091656069634048],
[0.00101689322921863]])
```

(Oscar already showed how to get numerical solutions for all roots.) If you now change one of the parameters by a small amount, you might find another solution near this solution. e.g. if you used g = 12 instead of g = 11 then you could do:

```py
>>> g = 12
>>> nsolve(eqs(),(x,y),(0.09,.001))  # using previous solution 
Matrix([
[  0.0839072097131664],
[0.000851016936303022]])
```